# How do I pass a XML file that is a URL into xmldatareader vb.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net

There is a XML file thats a URL address, I been trying to figure out how to pass this file into the vb.net XMLdataReader, I just can't see how to do this?  I want to strip some of the values of this xml file and store elsewhere.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[is this what you want?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162474%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
XmlReader.Create has an overload to create from a URI.
or at least you can use WebRequest.Create / GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream() as the parameter to create an XmlReader from the Stream overload